# Java cors issue in Play 2.5.4

Tags: java, playframework, cors

I am getting cors issues calling my API. To reesolve I am trying to add a CorsFilter but when I do activator dist and deploy to production I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/filters/cors/CORSFilter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:890)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:134)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build
```

I have "com.typesafe.play" % "filters-helpers_2.11" % "2.5.4" in my build.sbt

This is the filter code

```
import play.filters.cors.CORSFilter;
import play.http.DefaultHttpFilters;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Filters extends DefaultHttpFilters {
    @Inject public Filters(CORSFilter corsFilter) {
        super(corsFilter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the library being added to your deployment?  It's possible it's not being packaged.

Comment: I see com.typesafe.play.filters-helpers_2.11-2.5.4.jar in libs